# open pdf in new window using spring controlle and ajax

Tags: ajax, spring, pdf

I want to show the pdf file in new window.

Here is my code.

```
 <c:if test="${noOfOwners>0 && empty isOwner && licenseBean.businessBean.ownershipType==1}">        
     <c:url value="/auth/newlicense/ownercertification?retailerId=${licenseBean.outletID}" var="ownerCertificationUrl"/>
                <p class="label4"><a href="#" id="ownereligibilityForm">Owner Eligibility Certification</a></p>
                <p>For your license application to be approved, you must provide the lottery with a signed Owner Eligibility Certification form.  Each owner/officer included on the license application must sign the form, accepting the license eligibility standards, terms and conditions.  Instructions on returning the form to the Texas Lottery via mail, fax and email are included on the form.  To open a PDF version of the Owner Eligibility form, click on this link /link to form/.  A PDF version of the form has also been sent to the email address you provided</p>
   </c:if> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ownereligibilityForm").click(function(){
        var retailerid = <c:out value='${licenseBean.outletID}'/>;
        $.ajax({
            url : "ownercertification",
            type : "GET",
            data : {
                "retailerId" : retailerid
            },success : function(link){
                window.open(link,"_blank");
                return false;
            },error: function(){

            }
        });
    }); 
});

</script>
```

> my server side code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ownercertification", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String openOwnerEligibilityCertificationForm(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
    File file = new File("/var/lsp/licensing/21/output/"+request.getParameter("retailerId")+"/ownerEligibilityCertificationForm_"+request.getParameter("retailerId")+".pdf");
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+file);
    OutputStream out = null;
    try{
        byte[] b = new byte[(int)file.length()];
        out = response.getOutputStream();
        out.write(b);
        out.flush();
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return out.toString();
}
```

> But it is not opening the pdf file. I am getting the below error

HTTP Status 404 - /lsp/auth/newlicense/org.springframework.security.web.context.SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream[delegate=org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream@266f266f]

Could anyone help me?

Comment: post your full stacktrace

Comment: @dhamibirendra

I have a pdf file in c:/var/pdf/<retailerId>.pdf. In Jsp page I have a link with retailerId as request parameter. When user click on that link, I want to open the pdf in new window.

the application server is in C:/java/eside/server/jboss..

Comment: I got the solutions. In the anchor tag instead of using ajax simply use window.open('ownercertification')